# How do I create combinations from CSV in python?

Tags: python, csv

I have a python script that imports a CSV file to a dictionary like so:

```
import csv

with open('staff.csv') as csv_file:
  csv_reader = csv.DictReader(csv_file)
```

The `staff.csv` file has about 50 staff members and is formatted like this:

```
name,department,block
alex,accounting,1
ian,infotech,2
seth,security,2
rachel,research,3
miranda,manufacturing,3
```

I need to output all possible combinations of people listed in the file according to the following criteria:

- Each combination contains five people.
- Each person is in a different department.
- Each person is also in a different block.

The total output of all combinations should be written to a new file, such as `staff-sorted.csv`. The format and sorting aren't important but might look like this:

```
alex,accounting,1
bart,infotech,4
stacy,security,5
rachel,research,3
manny,manufacturing,2

hilda,infotech,5
nancy,accounting,4
manny,manufacturing,2
rachel,research,3
doug,security,1
```

How do I take these factors into account? I have no programming experience. I think it might work like this:

1. Add the first person's name to a "combination" array.
2. Add that department and block to an "occupied" array.
3. Go down the list to find the first person with an unoccupied department and block.
4. Add this person's name to the "combination" array and their department and block to the "occupied" array.
5. Repeat three more times to fill out the names array.

But I don't know how to do that, or how to make it go through to find other possible combinations...

Comment: Please share the code that shows how you currently load the data into dictionaries. Based on the example data you shared, please share an expected output - your descriptions aren't bad, but it's unclear how you expect those "combinations" to be represented. And do you need to just print some results, or do they need to go somewhere in some specific format?

Comment: I agree with Grismar's comment; could you provide the exact schema that you're looking for in the output?

Comment: I've updated the OP to show the CSV loading code, example output, and note that all possible combinations should be written to a single file.

Comment: it may need to use recursion. Get first person and find all person which could create pair with first person, for every pairs find all persons which could create group of three persons and create all groups, for every group find all persons which could match to create group of four persons, etc. it should be simpler with recursion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is code to iteratively do what you have asked. It uses a depth-first search (DFS) approach to traverse the input data and compile a list of all possible five-person groups meeting the selection criteria.

Someone with no programming experience would be hard-pressed to come up with this on their own. Alternative implementations using recursion instead of an explicit stack variable may also be out of reach for a beginning programmer. Nevertheless, hopefully this answer gives you a sense of how to approach problems like this.

```
        import collections
        # Assume the csv input data can be put into the following form:
        csvRows = [
            ('name','department','block'),
            ('alex','accounting','1'),
            ('ian','infotech','2'),
            ('seth','security','2'),
            ('rachel','research','3'),
            ('randy','research','3'),
            ('bart','infotech','4'),
            ('stacy','security','5'),
            ('manny','manufacturing','2'),
            ('hilda','infotech','5'),
            ('nancy','accounting','4'),
            ('doug','security','1')
        ]
        records = csvRows[1:]
        persons = {person:(dept, block) for person, dept, block in records}
        depts = defaultdict(lambda: defaultdict(list))
        for person, dept, block in records:
            depts[dept][block] += [person]
        csvResult = []
        groupsOf5 = set()
        groupOf5 = []
        deptsInGroup, blocksInGroup = set(), set()
        for person in persons:
            stack = [(person, False)]
            while stack:
                person, backtrack = stack.pop()
                curDept, curBlock = persons[person]
                if backtrack:
                    deptsInGroup.remove(curDept)
                    blocksInGroup.remove(curBlock)
                    groupOf5.pop()
                elif len(groupOf5) + 1 == 5:
                    groupOf5.append(person)
                    groupsOf5.add(tuple(sorted(groupOf5)))
                    groupOf5.pop()
                else:
                    groupOf5.append(person)
                    deptsInGroup.add(curDept)
                    blocksInGroup.add(curBlock)
                    toAdd = [(person, True)]
                    for dept, blocksInDept in depts.items():
                        if dept in deptsInGroup:
                            continue
                        for block, personsInBlock in blocksInDept.items():
                            if block in blocksInGroup:
                                continue
                            toAdd += zip(personsInBlock, cycle([False]))
                    stack += toAdd
        for group in groupsOf5:
            for person in group:
                csvResult.append((person, *persons[person]))
            csvResult.append(tuple()) #separator row
            
        [print(row) for row in csvResult]
```

The sample output looks like this:

```
('doug', 'security', '1')
('hilda', 'infotech', '5')
('manny', 'manufacturing', '2')
('nancy', 'accounting', '4')
('randy', 'research', '3')
()
('alex', 'accounting', '1')
('bart', 'infotech', '4')
('manny', 'manufacturing', '2')
('rachel', 'research', '3')
('stacy', 'security', '5')
()
('doug', 'security', '1')
('hilda', 'infotech', '5')
('manny', 'manufacturing', '2')
('nancy', 'accounting', '4')
('rachel', 'research', '3')
()
('alex', 'accounting', '1')
('bart', 'infotech', '4')
('manny', 'manufacturing', '2')
('randy', 'research', '3')
('stacy', 'security', '5')
()
```

Note that this answer does not focus on the details of getting the data in and out of csv files.

Comment: Thank you for your response! I tried to run your code, but got the following error:

line 18, in <module>
    depts = defaultdict(lambda: defaultdict(list))
NameError: name 'defaultdict' is not defined

Comment: @famed_farmer Try adding the line `import collections` to bring in the Python module containing the defaultdict datatype. You can also try using `collections.defaultdict` in place of `defaultdict`.

Comment: @famed_farmer, do you need any more help getting my answer to work?

Comment: No help needed, this works exactly right! All I had to do was add `import collections` and set `collections.defaultdict` like you said!